# pass by reference recursion function

Tags: c++, recursion, pass-by-reference

I am having a hard time understanding how pass by reference is affecting the below recursive function.

```
bool isMeasureable(int target, vector<int>& weight){
    if (weight.empty()) {
       return target==0;
    }else{
       int value = weight.front();
       weight.erase(weight.begin());
       vector<int> rest=weight;

       return isMeasureable(target, rest)
       || isMeasureable(target-value, rest)
       || isMeasureable(target+value, rest);
   }
}
```

this function basically checks whether an amount can be measured with the given weights. As an example,
if the vector weight contains 1 and 3, the function returns true if the target is either 2 (as 3 - 1 =2) or 4 (as 1+3 =4).
Without the reference syntax to the vector weight, the function works fine. However, when I do pass by reference, the function returns wrong result.

I know the problem has to do with pass by reference, but can someone pinpoint the exact place where pass by reference is causing this problem?

//EDIT: This code seems to work even with pass by reference. The only change is assignment to the vector rest is made first then the vector rest was modified.

```
bool isMeasureable(int target, vector<int> & weight){
    if (weight.empty()) {
        return target==0;
    }else{
        int value = weight.front();
        vector<int> rest=weight; // change made
        rest.erase(rest.begin()); //change made

       return isMeasureable(target, rest)
       || isMeasureable(target-value, rest)
       || isMeasureable(target+value, rest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every call to `isMeasureable` slices an element off the front of the vector passed in as a parameter. `rest` has different contents when passed to three recursive `isMeasurable` calls - it gets one element shorter with each call.

Instead of physically modifying the vector, pass an extra parameter to `isMeasurable` - and offset at which to start working. Increment this offset when making recursive calls. Then pass `weights` by const reference, and don't make any copies.